# GSA Wildcard search and suggestion not working together

Tags: wildcard, spell-checking, search-suggestion, google-search-appliance

I'm using GSA 7.2 version which supports wildcard search but as soon as I enable it then spelling suggestions stop appearing. Please take a look below URL and suggest what should be done so that I start getting it.

http:// {host-name}/search?start=0&num=1000&site=xyzTest&output=xml&client=frontend&filter=0&getfields=*&q=sken*

In the above query, search term is "sken", GSA suggestion tag should appear and provide suggestion for "skin" but it is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Is spelling suggestion enabled in your frontend?
If not enable it by setting 1 to the show_spelling variable in the xslt.
i.e:     `<xsl:variable name="show_spelling">1</xsl:variable>`

Answer (score 0):

From the GSA Documentation:

> When using daterange or inmeta queries, spelling suggestions are not returned.
>   To view spelling suggestions, use the requiredfields parameter instead of inmeta